# Azure form recognizer does not identifies any Keys

Tags: azure, api, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I'm  using the Microsoft custom model API for the form recognizer, I test it first with the example they have in this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool

The problem I have now, is that for any other form, that is not the one in the example, the recognizer does not recognizes properly any key-value pair.

E.G.

For the below form:

[image]

I get the response as:

[image]

Where any of the values is mapped to its key. E.G. for "Receiving Officer" the value should be "Ramon"  but instead I'm getting them as token_2 and token_5, which is information I can not use.

It is suspicious to me, that this happens for all the forms I have tried, aside from the example.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to train with labels follow this quick start and see if it extracts the values you need - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool

try out site - https://fott.azurewebsites.net/

How do you get the response as this looks like the train without labels response where text which is not associated with a key is outputted as Tokens.